# My tableView methods have poor performance

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

I have two problems (in fact one - my code sucks):

1. My table takes a long time to load(about 5 seconds)
2. She is dreadfully poor

Any ideas?

My tableView methods:

```c
// Table
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    RefreshDelegate *RefreshProtocol = [[RefreshDelegate new] autorelease];
    RefreshProtocol.delegate = self;

return [[RefreshProtocol returnDataForTable] count];

}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    RefreshDelegate *RefreshProtocol = [[RefreshDelegate new] autorelease];
    RefreshProtocol.delegate = self;


    NSArray *curent = [self curent:section];
    return [curent count];
}

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section { 
    RefreshDelegate *RefreshProtocol = [[RefreshDelegate new] autorelease];
    RefreshProtocol.delegate = self;

    return [[[RefreshProtocol returnDataForTable] allKeys] objectAtIndex:section];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault 
                                       reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    NSArray *curent = [self curent:indexPath.section];
    cell.textLabel.text = [curent objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}

- (NSArray*)curent:(NSInteger)index {
    RefreshDelegate *RefreshProtocol = [[RefreshDelegate new] autorelease];
    RefreshProtocol.delegate = self;

    NSArray *keys = [[RefreshProtocol returnDataForTable] allKeys];
    NSString *curentKey = [keys objectAtIndex:index];
    NSArray *curent = [[RefreshProtocol returnDataForTable] objectForKey:curentKey];
    return curent;
}
```

My RefreshProtocol methods:

```c
#define MaxCountPair 7
-(NSDictionary *)returnDataForTable{  
    NSMutableArray *day_1 = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:MaxCountPair];
    NSMutableArray *day_2 = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:MaxCountPair];
    NSMutableArray *day_3 = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:MaxCountPair];
    NSMutableArray *day_4 = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:MaxCountPair];
    NSMutableArray *day_5 = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:MaxCountPair];
    NSMutableArray *day_6 = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:MaxCountPair];


    // Analysis db and write array today
    NSArray *array = [SQLiteAccess selectManyRowsWithSQL:@"select * from schedule"];
    for (int i = 0; i < [array count]; i++) {
        NSDictionary *dictionary = [array objectAtIndex:i];

        if ([self checkOverlapDigit:[[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"numberWeek"] objectForKey:@"numberWeek"]:[dictionary objectForKey:@"week"]] && [self checkOverlapDigit:[self subgroupToInt]:[dictionary objectForKey:@"subgroup"]]) {
            if ([self checkDay:[[dictionary objectForKey:@"day"] intValue]]) {
                [day_1 addObject:[dictionary objectForKey:@"subject"]]; 
            }
            else {
                if ([self checkDay:[[dictionary objectForKey:@"day"] intValue] - 1]) {
                    [day_2 addObject:[dictionary objectForKey:@"subject"]];
                }
                else {
                    if ([self checkDay:[[dictionary objectForKey:@"day"] intValue] - 2]) {

                        [day_3 addObject:[dictionary objectForKey:@"subject"]];
                    }
                    else {
                        if ([self checkDay:[[dictionary objectForKey:@"day"] intValue] - 3]) {
                            [day_4 addObject:[dictionary objectForKey:@"subject"]];
                        }
                        else {
                            if ([self checkDay:[[dictionary objectForKey:@"day"] intValue] - 4]) {
                                [day_5 addObject:[dictionary objectForKey:@"subject"]];
                            }
                            else {
                                if ([self checkDay:[[dictionary objectForKey:@"day"] intValue] - 5]) {
                                    [day_6 addObject:[dictionary objectForKey:@"subject"]];
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    NSDictionary *days = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:day_1, @"1", day_2, @"2", day_3, @"3", day_4, @"4", day_5, @"5", day_6, @"6", nil];


    return days;
}

-(NSString *)removeAllButDigit:(NSString *)originalString{
    // Remove all but digit
    NSMutableString *strippedString = [NSMutableString 
                                       stringWithCapacity:originalString.length];

    NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:originalString];
    NSCharacterSet *numbers = [NSCharacterSet 
                               characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"1234"];

    while ([scanner isAtEnd] == NO) {
        NSString *buffer;
        if ([scanner scanCharactersFromSet:numbers intoString:&buffer]) {
            [strippedString appendString:buffer];
        } else {
            [scanner setScanLocation:([scanner scanLocation] + 1)];
        }
    }

    return strippedString;
}

-(BOOL)checkDay:(NSInteger)day{
    NSString *currentDay = nil;
    switch (day) {
        case 1:
            currentDay = NSLocalizedString(@"_monday", nil);
            break;
        case 2:
            currentDay = NSLocalizedString(@"_tuesday", nil);
            break;
        case 3:
            currentDay = NSLocalizedString(@"_wednesday", nil);
            break;
        case 4:
            currentDay = NSLocalizedString(@"_thursday", nil);
            break;
        case 5:
            currentDay = NSLocalizedString(@"_friday", nil);
            break;
        case 6:
            currentDay = NSLocalizedString(@"_saturday", nil);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];  
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEEE"];
    if ([currentDay isEqualToString:[dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]]]) {
        return YES;
    }
    return NO;
}


-(BOOL)checkOverlapDigit:(NSString *)smallerString:(NSString *)largerString{
    if ([largerString isEqualToString:@"0"]) {
        return YES;
    }

    NSInteger intSmaller = [[self removeAllButDigit:smallerString] intValue];
    NSInteger intLarger = [[self removeAllButDigit:largerString] intValue];

    while (1) {
        if (intLarger % 10 != 0) {
            NSInteger sedimentWeek = intLarger % 10;
            if (sedimentWeek == intSmaller) {
                return YES;
            }
            intLarger /= 10;
        }
        else {
            if (intLarger / 10 != 0) {
                intLarger /= 10;
                if (intLarger == intSmaller) {
                    return YES;
                }
            }
            else {
                return NO;
            }
        }
    }
}

-(NSString *)subgroupToInt{
    if ([[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"subgroupValue"] isEqualToString: @"subgroupValue1"]) {
        return @"1";
    }
    else
        if ([[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"subgroupValue"] isEqualToString: @"subgroupValue2"]) {
            return @"2";

        }
        else
            if ([[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"subgroupValue"] isEqualToString: @"subgroupValue3"]) {
                return @"3";
            }
    return @"4";
}
```

And SQLiteAccess class: [.h](http://pastebin.com/nj9Y5p3G), [.m](http://pastebin.com/kbFyREqT)

Comment: Why not profile the code in `Instruments`?

Comment: I just can not understand what inhibits

Comment: That's why you ask `Instruments` to tell you.  If you want to solve the issue then go and use it and stop dithering.

Comment: Wow, his is similar to what I need. Thank you I'm sorry, I did not know about this tool. Just learning

Comment: This may not help much with your issue. However, conventions help communicating and therefore searching for help here and they help avoding errors. Two issues so far: 1. you should name RefreshProtocol refreshProtocol instead. It is an object(-pointer) not a class. More important: avoid giving local objects (curent) the name of a more global object (e.g. a class variable or method). The local one hides the class variable. You did it right as, far as I have seen so far, but doing so carries a high potential of making mistakes.

Comment: There is no point in creating a RefreshProtocol object so often. This may not solve your issue but as far as I can see, you may want to use a singleton pattern here. Implement a factory method (a class method) like 'getRefreshProtocol' which either creates a RefreshProtocol object and stores it in a class variable (not an instance variable) if that very variable is nil or just returns the value of that class variable if the object has been created before. Google for singleton pattern.

Comment: Thanks, I'll do. But it seems to me that it can not cause the brakes.. Or am I wrong? 

I can not find a leak, the `Instruments ` displays an error `Target failed to run: Remote exception encountered: 'Failed to get task for pid %pid_app%'`

Comment: @Oshevnev I edited my answer (before you deleted your comment..)

Comment: Thank you all, now I know what I need to do and how to look for leaks. I will try to correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For starting... you can (you have) to create you object only once!! (in the constructor? In `-viewDidLoad` ?)

Then in the tableView delegate methods you access your (unique) object.

EDIT:
Adds a property in your class:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) RefreshDelegate* refreshProtocol;
```

In your `-viewDidLoad` method add

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.refreshProtocol = [[RefreshDelegate new] autorelease];
    self.refreshProtocol.delegate = self;
}
```

Now:

```
- (NSArray*)curent:(NSInteger)index {    

    NSArray *keys = [[self.refreshProtocol returnDataForTable] allKeys];
    NSString *curentKey = [keys objectAtIndex:index];
    NSArray *curent = [[self.refreshProtocol returnDataForTable] objectForKey:curentKey];
    return curent;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSArray *curent = [self curent:section];
    return [curent count];
}
```

... and correct the other methods...